# A Sales RepMIN, MAX, and AVG

Tags: sql

I am trying to find a SalesReps Lowest Cost Order, their average cost and their highest cost. I am expecting the output to be something like.

```
[SalesRep]     [Max]     [AVG]     [Min]
 #12121         12         6         2
```

The Code I currently have is

```
SELECT DISTINCT REP, MAX(Amount), AVG(Amount), MIN(Amount)
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-30';
```

I understand the Select statement is wrong I just don't know where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the missing `group by`:

```
select REP,
    MAX(Amount),
    AVG(Amount),
    MIN(Amount)
from Orders
where OrderDate between '1990-01-01' and '1999-12-30'
group by REP --<-- here
```

Comment: Thank you this worked but, I tried adding a AND clause afterwards and now getting an error telling me Group function not allowed here. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: @JoshKing - Are you trying to add another filter condition to the where clause? If so, add it before the `group by`.

Comment: WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-30'
AND COUNT(Amount) > 1
GROUP BY REP;         This is how I have it in my code written and there is no error until I run it. The error reads as: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 28 Column: 5

Comment: @Josh You want `group by rep having count(amount) > 1`